# How to show only one value in select2 multiple?

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

The default view is

[image]

I want to show only one item and make like a single select. how can i limit the values? Please help me to solve this.

Comment: Give out some more details otherwise none can help you.

Comment: Issue has been solved by using jquery ui autocomplete .. thanks mate.